# Updating address for swag delivery

Tags: support, swag

Reading [this recent question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/has-anyone-received-their-swag-package), I realise: my address has changed since I originally gave it; is there a way to update it, for me and anyone else in this situation?

(I revisited the form and submitted with my up-to-date address, but I’m guessing all that did was to duplicate my entry in some database, since it never acknowledged the fact I’d already submitted; my apologies if having duplicate entries causes a headache for anyone up in the cloud…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email `team+english@stackexchange.com` with your new address and the fact that you submitted a duplicate form.